# Read JSON from PHP with cookie

Tags: java, php, android, cookies

I´m building an app for a existing website which uses JavaScript and PHP. Now I want to get JSON from PHP, but the PHP needs a cookie to give the correct value. The cookie is made while logging in to the website. I can't get it to work in my Java code. It reads the JSON from the PHP but the value is always 0 because it doesn't get the cookie.

The code I have to get the JSON value:

```
private void postPHP() throws IOException, JSONException {

    URL url = new URL("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php"); // URL to your application
    Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("rekeningnr", ""); // All parameters, also easy

    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    // POST as urlencoded is basically key-value pairs, as with GET
    // This creates key=value&key=value&... pairs
    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }

    // Convert string to byte array, as it should be sent
    byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    // Connect, easy
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    // Tell server that this is POST and in which format is the data
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

    // This gets the output from your server
    Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        System.out.print((char)c);
// Do something with http.getInputStream()

}

private void getData() throws IOException, JSONException {
    TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
    try {
        String response = json.getString("saldo");
        Log.e("saldo", response);
        response = json.getString("saldo");
        txtUser.setText(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code to login is:

```
private void checkLogin(final String user, final String pass) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
           AppConfig.URL_LOGIN , new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                int login1 = jObj.getInt("howislife");
                System.out.println(login1);
                //Check for error node in json
                if (login1 == 1) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);


                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else if(login1 == 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wachtwoord verkeerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(login1 == 3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gebruikersnaam of/en wachtwoord verkeerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Er is iets fout gegaan, probeer opnieuw.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("user", user);
            params.put("pass", pass);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

How can I get the cookie and use it to get the correct value from the getSaldo.php?

EDIT: Okay, I just found out you can create a cookie yourself, the website stores that cookie and remembers it for some time. That makes it a bit easier. So now my question is how can I send a cookie to the PHP so it stores it on the server and gives the correct JSON value?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133993/sending-cookie-info-in-httprequest?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I can't get it to work in my code, sorry, I'm a complete noob with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(SystemConstants.URL_COOKIE); 
    URL url = new URL(urlToServer);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);
    connection.connect();
    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data.getBytes());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

Comment: And how do I implement this into my code? I tried it but it doesn't work. It says 'cannot resolve method "getInstance"'

Comment: can you  post the error message please, check logcat

Comment: \MainActivity.java:159: error: cannot find symbol
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method getInstance()
  location: class CookieManager
\MainActivity.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
        String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(SystemConstants.URL_COOKIE);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable SystemConstants
  location: class MainActivity
2 errors

You mean this?

Comment: I guess you used wrong import, can you check if you imported InputManager from correct package, and that is not error , it just compilation error as your IDE couldn't find the references.

Comment: I changed the import package, now the getInstance works. Only the SystemConstants cannot be resolved. What do I have to do with that?

Comment: And itn't this code for requesting a cookie instead of sending one to the server? I can make a cookie myself at logging in, but it needs to be sent to the server so it remembers it to that login.

Comment: you can retrieve the data from mysql server by volley library check it out with cookies

Comment: Nevermind, it is the right code I guess. I just can't get it to work. If i implement it in my code I get all kind of errors because the piece of code alone doesn't work and I don't know what's missing.

Comment: \MainActivity.java:143: error: cannot find symbol
        String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(SystemConstants.URL_COOKIE);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable SystemConstants
  location: class MainActivity
\MainActivity.java:151: error: int cannot be dereferenced
        out.write(data.getBytes());

Comment: String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(SystemConstants.URL_COOKIE);

Comment: try to use  String.valueOf(cookieManager.getCookie(SystemConstants.URL_COOKIE));

Comment: Okay I now did private void postPHP (String host) throws IOException, JSONException and changed the 143 line to String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(host); and it kinda workt. Now I only need to set the host string myself I guess, so it sends that cookie to the server?

Comment: I already set the string by calling the postPHP in the OnCreate, but it doesn't work unfortunatly. I think because I haven't set the name of the cookie anywhere. The name of the cookie needs to be "thatsallfolks", and the value can be the username given in at the login or whatever

Comment: Also in the logcat it sais "W/System: Ignoring header Cookie because its value was null."

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem... This is the code I have now to get the JSON value from the server:

```
private void postPHP (String cookie1) throws IOException, JSONException {

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookieString = cookieManager.getCookie(cookie1);
    URL url = new URL("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("thatsallfolks", cookieString);
    connection.connect();
    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

private void getData() throws IOException, JSONException {
    TextView txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://piggybank.wordmediavormgever.nl/getSaldo.php");
    try {
        String response = json.getString("saldo");
        Log.e("saldo", response);
        response = json.getString("saldo");
        txtUser.setText(response);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see it just uses the getData part to display the JSON value, it just igores the postPHP part. And I don't know how to combine them together so it first sends the request with the cookie and then gets the JSON response which has to show in the TextView. I think that's what's going wrong. Now it just reads the JSON from the url without sending the cookie.